# Abort a ajax request in Webix Ajax

Tags: ajax, webix

For XMHhttpRequest we have a method to abort. but how to use this method in webix ajax request ?

For XMLHttpRequest we can cancel request like this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to abort the ajax call.
If you really need to access the XHR object you can use something like next

```js
var lastXHR = null;
webix.attachEvent("onBeforeAjax", function(mode, url, params, xhr){
  lastXHR = xhr;
});

// Now you can abort ajax call like
webix.ajax("/some/data");
lastXHR.abort();
```

Also, beware that if you are loading data into the component through .load API or "url" parameter, ajax call will be aborted on component destruction.